# OpenGL ES 2.0, how to animate texture's opacity

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 to create the following scene:

Draw a background image on the entire screen and above it draw another overlay image that fades in and out (alpha changes)

I also need to use "`Screen blend`" to blend the overlay and the background textures.

So I created a shader that blends the two textures, I thought that I can use a uniform (`randomAlpha`) to change the overlay texture alpha over time and create a fade animation, but the following code doesn't do the trick, the overlay texture opacity doesn't changes!

I know there is an "Alpha Blend" that I can use to blend the overlay and the background textures, but the problem is that I want the final overlay (after opacity changes) to blend the background with a "Screen Blend" not an "Alpha Blend"

This is how my fragment shader main method looks like:

```
 void main()
 {
     mediump vec4 background = texture2D(backgroundTexture, backgroundCoords);
     mediump vec4 overlay = texture2D(overlayTexture, overlayCoords);

     overlay.a = randomAlpha;

     // add overlay to background (using screen blend)
     mediump vec4 whiteColor = vec4(1.0);
     gl_FragColor = whiteColor - ((whiteColor - overlay) * (whiteColor - background));

  }
```

Clearly I missing something important here..
How can I change the texture's opacity? how can I create the fade effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you already figured it's just a matter of blending.

What you're missing is that you need to re-calculate the `rgb` channels, when you change the `alpha` value when you want to blend to textures together.

```
void main()
{
    mediump vec4 background = texture2D(backgroundTexture, backgroundCoords);
    mediump vec4 overlay = texture2D(overlayTexture, overlayCoords);

    overlay.a = randomAlpha;
    background.a = 1.0 - overlay.a;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(background.rgb * background.a + overlay.rgb * overlay.a, 1.0);
}
```

Here is a simplified version of the above code, the above code is just easier to understand and read.

```
void main()
{
    mediump vec4 background = texture2D(backgroundTexture, backgroundCoords);
    mediump vec4 overlay = texture2D(overlayTexture, overlayCoords);

    overlay.rgb *= randomAlpha;
    background.rgb *= 1.0 - randomAlpha;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(background.rgb + overlay.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: so if I want to change the color alpha to 50% opacity I actually need to multiply the entire vec4 by 0.5?

Comment: Yes if you want to blend two colors, then you need to multiply each color's alpha with the color's red, green, blue channels. Before you can add the two colors together.

Comment: Or even simpler using the [builtin `mix` function](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/mix.xml): `gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(background.rgb, overlay.rgb, randomAlpha), 1.0);`.

Comment: @ChristianRau The OP wanted to keep the alpha of the texture, so that won't work.

Comment: @Vallentin Whatever the OP wanted, my example does *exactly* what your code does.